# Why binding M-Z to a command in org-mode with (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-Z>") 'my-command) fails?

Tags: key-bindings

For Emacs 26.3 running in terminal mode, I am trying to map a `my-command` to <kbd>M-Z</kbd> in org-mode by using the following code:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load org
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-Z>") #'my-command))
```

But this does not work.

It works if I do this instead:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load org
    (define-key esc-map "Z" #'my-command))
```

But the latter binds `my-command` in the global map making it available everywhere, and I do not want that.

This behaves as if the `esc-map` takes precedence over the `org-mode-map`.  I looked in org.el and I don't see that code copying anything from the `esc-map` defined in subr.el.

I thought it could because the org mode function has not yet run, so I tried adding the code inside a `org-mode-hook` as well (in addition to the above code):

```lisp
  (defun pel--org-set-keys ()
    "Set keys."
    (if (boundp 'org-mode-map)
        (progn
          (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-Z>") #'my-command))
      (display-warning 'pel--org-set-keys
                       "org-mode-map not bound"
                       :error)))
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (function pel--org-set-keys))
```

But that still does not work.

Why does the `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-Z>") #'my-command)` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `(kbd "<M-Z>")`. You want `(kbd "M-Z")`.

`kbd` expects the same key-description (name) syntax as that used by Emacs itself in `*Help*`.  If you use `C-h k` followed by <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> then Emacs tells you that this is key `M-z`, not key `<M-Z>`.

Comment: It's been one of those days...   Thanks.

Comment: ;-)  It's easy to get confused with this stuff. Not to mention that the key description of `M-Z` is `M-Z`, but the key description of Ctrl + Shift + z is `C-S-z`, not `C-Z`!

Comment: :-), I started off modifying something that was `<M-right>` and wanted to transform it into `M-Z` and forgot to remove the angle brackets.  Staring at the code I did not see the nasty angle brackets and was digging into how the key maps were handled...  I also was focusing on the esc-map becuase of what I was into.  I know that stuff, I should have just been looking at what I wrote...  Oh well...

Comment: Thinking about it, I think I was focussing on what I might not know instead of what I knew... That's an example of why team work and code reviews are important!